# Flutter Riverpod: using ref.watch in the constructor for a ChangeNotifier, how to avoid Notifier being recreated upon changes

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-state

I have a ChangeNotifier, which I use with ChangeNotifierProvider to track the state of a screen in my app. It has a constructor:

```
CategoryViewState(ProviderRefBase ref, int listId) {

    subjects = ref.watch(otherProvider.select((value) => value.getSubjects()));

}
```

The problem I'm encountering is that when otherProvider.getSubjects() changes, the whole ChangeNotifier is recreated from scratch, rather than the subjects list being updated. This means the state of the page is lost.

Is there a fix or another way to do this that avoids this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the widget that list to the changes in a Consumer widget and watch changes inside it:

```
Consumer(builder: (context, ref, child) {
  final subjects = ref.watch(otherProvider.select((value) => value.getSubjects()));
  return YourWidget(); // Just this widget will be rebuilt
},)
```